# How to pass a variables to wifiManager by Tapzu for esp 8266, i want to be able to pass mqtt id and password

Tags: mqtt, iot, esp8266, wifimanager, arduino-esp8266

I am able to configure the esp8266 using the tapzu wifi manager, i would also like to send the mqtt server id and password from the wifi configure page so that the esp can connect to the mqtt server. I do not want to be flashing the esp every-time, any resources would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom parameters to WiFiManager by:

```
// id/name, placeholder/prompt, default, length
WiFiManagerParameter custom_mqtt_server("server", "mqtt server", mqtt_server, 40);
wifiManager.addParameter(&custom_mqtt_server);
```

And you can retrieve the values by

```
mqtt_server = custom_mqtt_server.getValue();
```

For more details see the [documentation](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager#custom-parameters)